# Django REST Framework Swagger 2.0

Tags: django, django-rest-framework, swagger-ui, swagger-2.0, openapi

Having a hard time configuring Swagger UI
Here are the very explanatory docs: https://django-rest-swagger.readthedocs.io/en/latest/

YAML docstrings are deprecated. Does somebody know how to configure Swagger UI from within the python code? or what file should I change to group api endpoints, to add comments to each endpoint, to add query parameter fields in Swagger UI?

Comment: Do you have an example of the kind of grouping you want to do e.g. on another Swagger-based API? Swagger can be quite limiting in terms of grouping – I wrote bespoke templates to do this. Comments I imagine are added from docstrings on the endpoint methods. Query parameters should appear if they're correctly defined… though I vaguely remember there being circumstances where they're not.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This is how I managed to do it:

base urls.py

```
urlpatterns = [
...
url(r'^api/', include('api.urls', namespace='api')),
url(r'^api-auth/', include('rest_framework.urls', namespace='rest_framework')),
...
]
```

api.urls.py

```
urlpatterns = [
url(r'^$', schema_view, name='swagger'),
url(r'^article/(?P<pk>[0-9]+)/$', 
    ArticleDetailApiView.as_view(actions={'get': 'get_article_by_id'}), 
    name='article_detail_id'),
url(r'^article/(?P<name>.+)/(?P<pk>[0-9]+)/$', 
    ArticleDetailApiView.as_view(actions={'get': 'get_article'}), 
    name='article_detail'),
]
```

api.views.py. In MyOpenAPIRenderer  I update the data dict to add description, query fields and to update type or required features.

```
class MyOpenAPIRenderer(OpenAPIRenderer):
    def add_customizations(self, data):
        super(MyOpenAPIRenderer, self).add_customizations(data)
        data['paths']['/article/{name}/{pk}/']['get'].update(
            {'description': 'Some **description**',
             'parameters': [{'description': 'Add some description',
                             'in': 'path',
                             'name': 'pk',
                             'required': True,
                             'type': 'integer'},
                            {'description': 'Add some description',
                             'in': 'path',
                             'name': 'name',
                             'required': True,
                             'type': 'string'},
                            {'description': 'Add some description',
                             'in': 'query',
                             'name': 'a_query_param',
                             'required': True,
                             'type': 'boolean'},
                            ]
             })
        # data['paths']['/article/{pk}/']['get'].update({...})
        data['basePath'] = '/api'  

@api_view()
@renderer_classes([MyOpenAPIRenderer, SwaggerUIRenderer])
def schema_view(request):
    generator = SchemaGenerator(title='A title', urlconf='api.urls')
    schema = generator.get_schema(request=request)
    return Response(schema)


class ArticleDetailApiView(ViewSet):

    @detail_route(renderer_classes=(StaticHTMLRenderer,))
    def get_article_by_id(self, request, pk):
        pass

    @detail_route(renderer_classes=(StaticHTMLRenderer,))
    def get_article(self, request, name, pk):
        pass
```

**update for django-rest-swagger (2.0.7)**: replace only *add_customizations* with *get_customizations*.

views.py

```
class MyOpenAPIRenderer(OpenAPIRenderer):
    def get_customizations(self):
        data = super(MyOpenAPIRenderer, self).get_customizations()
        data['paths'] = custom_data['paths']
        data['info'] = custom_data['info']
        data['basePath'] = custom_data['basePath']
        return data
```

You can read the [swagger specification](http://swagger.io/specification/) to create custom data.

Comment: Where exactly did you find `add_customizations`? I cannot find it in the source code at all. As a result, this solution is not working for me.

Comment: Not sure what version that this patch relates to but django-rest-swagger==2.1.0 does not contain `add_customizations` or any similar named function that contains the 'data' variable that is described above

Comment: In the last example, is `custom_data` user-defined?

Comment: Yes, you can look at swagger specification to create it as mentioned in the answer.

Answer (score 7):

So, it seems that what happened is django-rest-frameowrk [added the new SchemeGenerator](https://github.com/tomchristie/django-rest-framework/pull/4179), but it is half-baked and missing the ability to generate action descriptions from code docs, and have an [open issue about it](https://github.com/tomchristie/django-rest-framework/issues/4241), due in 3.5.0.

In the meanwhile, django-rest-swagger went ahead and updated their code to work with the new SchemaGenerator, which makes it a [breaking change](http://marcgibbons.github.io/django-rest-swagger/#changes-in-20) for now.

Very weird series of events led to this ): hoping this will be resolved soon. for now, the proposed answer is the only option.

Answer (score 7):

**EDIT** - since swagger version 2.2.0 and rest framework 3.9.2 create a custom schema like this:

```
from rest_framework.schemas import AutoSchema


class CustomSchema(AutoSchema):
    def get_link(self, path, method, base_url):
        link = super().get_link(path, method, base_url)
        link._fields += self.get_core_fields()
        return link

    def get_core_fields(self):
        return getattr(self.view, 'coreapi_fields', ())
```

Then, just use the `DEFAULT_SCHEMA_CLASS` setting.

```
REST_FRAMEWORK = {
    'DEFAULT_SCHEMA_CLASS': 'common.schema.CustomSchema',
}
```

---

**! The below approach is obsolete.**

Since I couldn't find any viable option [here](https://github.com/tomchristie/django-rest-framework/blob/master/rest_framework/schemas.py#L371-L374) I simply created my own SchemaGenerator, like this:

```
from rest_framework.schemas import SchemaGenerator


class MySchemaGenerator(SchemaGenerator):   
    title = 'REST API Index'

    def get_link(self, path, method, view):
        link = super(MySchemaGenerator, self).get_link(path, method, view)
        link._fields += self.get_core_fields(view)
        return link

    def get_core_fields(self, view):
        return getattr(view, 'coreapi_fields', ())
```

Created the swagger view:

```
from rest_framework.permissions import AllowAny
from rest_framework.renderers import CoreJSONRenderer
from rest_framework.response import Response
from rest_framework.views import APIView
from rest_framework_swagger import renderers


class SwaggerSchemaView(APIView):
    _ignore_model_permissions = True
    exclude_from_schema = True
    permission_classes = [AllowAny]
    renderer_classes = [
        CoreJSONRenderer,
        renderers.OpenAPIRenderer,
        renderers.SwaggerUIRenderer
    ]

    def get(self, request):
        generator = MySchemaGenerator()
        schema = generator.get_schema(request=request)

        return Response(schema)
```

Use this view in urls.py:

```
url(r'^docs/$', SwaggerSchemaView.as_view()),
```

Add a custom field within an APIView:

```
class EmailValidator(APIView):
    coreapi_fields = (
        coreapi.Field(
            name='email',
            location='query',
            required=True,
            description='Email Address to be validated',
            type='string'
        ),
    )

    def get(self, request):
        return Response('something')
```

Answer (score 0):

Using the proposed solution is a bit hacky but works fine, one may face few issues implementing the proposed solution but this doc explains django rest swagger 2 integration as well as the issues faced step by step:
[Django Rest Swagger 2 comprehensive documentation](https://github.com/m-haziq/django-rest-swagger-docs)

Much late but it may help someone looking for help now.